# How can I make partialy deployed solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Is it possible to create .NET MVC Core C# solution with multiple apps or modules and based on client selection of which app/module he wants to have I can deploy only selected apps/modules?
I need to deploy the only selected app/module and not include other apps/modules and the solution should work without breaking dependencies (such as classes).
I dont need to deploy each app in different C# application because that requires to install them on separate ports on IIS.
Similar scenarios I can refer to are: Zoho CRM or Odoo, user can select apps/modules that he likes to enable and start using them in his workspace

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, please post more details information about your requirement.

Comment: Ok, I have MVC C# solution with couple of apps inside (App1, App2 & App3) if certain client is interested in my solution but App1 only, I cannot have a copy of my solution having App1 only and delete other apps and package/deploy only App1 as that may break dependency. So my question was: what is the best methodology that I can follow to build my solution with a modular apps structure in which I can deploy only specific apps in my solution